# Firestore Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a new record like the one below to a Firestore document using a function deployed to firebase. The function is developed in typescript:

Function:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
const app = express();

app.put('/v2/MYENDPOINT/add', async (req, res) => {
    try 
    {
        const res1 = db.collection('Bars2')
                         .doc('NHn8368LhIhNWHTOaEDo')
                         .update({
                            name: req.body['name'],
                            address: req.body['address1']
                          }).then(function() {
                            res.status(200).send(`Created a new Real bar2: ${(res1)}`)
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            res.status(400).send("Error writing document: " + error);
                        });


        //res.status(200).send(`Created a new Real bar2: ${(res1)}`)
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        res.status(400).send(`Real bar2 not created!!! ${error}`)
    }        
})
```

I try with postman to add this item but the code is triggering an error:

Postman New Request
{
    "name": "BAR C",
    "address": "qwerty"
}

> Real bar2 not created!!! Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore value. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "address"). If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

Firestore structure is in the image attached.

Any ideas what I am missing? Thanks

[image]

[[image: How I Would Like the Data To Look On Right Side Of Image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to the error message is this:

> Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "address").

Your address field is undefined, which is not a valid value for Firestore documents.  That means `req.body['address1']` is undefined.

Perhaps you meant to say "address" instead of "address1".

Comment: Thanks Doug, I have modified the Put request in Postman and the data is now added, but not as I would expect. I need the data to be a new map item under the bars array. I have updated the first post with a new image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/psnDq.png    [I assume the .update( part of the code is wrong, but I just cant see what I need to do to change this] The way I'd like it to look is on the right of the new image, what currently happens is in yellow on the left.

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately.  Stack Overflow is not good for handling back-and-forth issues.  There is a limit of one question per post, in order to be helpful for others who might have the same specific problem.

Comment: OK, thanks Doug. It wont let me post another question for 90 mins.